# I want the input data to go into the title and the textarea data to go into the content

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

```
    import React  from 'react';
    export default class CreateNote extend React.component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {note:{title:" ",content:" "}  };
        console.log(this.state);
      }
     const inputEvent = (event) => {
            const value = event.target.value;
            const name = event.target.name;
            this.setState({
              note:{title:    ,content:    }
         })
        }
    render(){ 
    return(  
        <input 
       type="text" 
       placeholder="Title"
       name="title"
       id=""
       value={note.title}
       onChange={inputEvent}
      /> 
    <textarea 
         name="contant" 
         id=""
         value={note.contant}
         cols="" 
         rows=""
         placeholder="Write a Notes"
         onChange={inputEvent}
         onClick={expanded}>
    </textarea>
    )
    }
```

When I write text in the input field and textarea then do not go data to note state. I want the input data to go into the title and the textarea data to go into the content.
Now I will write what on setState? I want to see result in the console.

Comment: Side note: there is a typo in `value={note.contant}` ....  contant vs content

Answer (score 0):

Tip: Your code is riddled with errors and typos (e.g., `CreateNote extend React.component` instead of `CreateNote extends React.Component` , writing `const` for a function inside a Class Component, `contant` instead of `content`). For better chances of getting a help, kindly post the working code that you have, so that duplicating the issue becomes easier for the people looking to help you.

Now on to the solution. If you are  a beginner, the best way to get what you want is to make separate functions - one that is triggered when the text inside the `input` is changed, and the other which is triggered when the text inside `textarea` is changed.

Note that you have kept `title` and `content` inside a state object `note`. This means in order to change `title` or `content`, you have to update the entire `note` object. Be careful if you update just one key of `note` without persisting the other one (e.g., if you update `title` only and want to leave `content` unaffected), you should use the spread operator `...` which helps to clone the object's values, so then after that you can update the value of the key you want.

```
 titleChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      note: {
        ...this.state.note,
        title: e.target.value
      }
    });
  };

  contentChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      note: {
        ...this.state.note,
        content: e.target.value
      }
    });
  };
```

**Update, a cleaner approach**: We can also use the "name" attribute of the input and textarea to our benefit and combine the two functions into one (I've named it `inputChange` )

```
inputChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      note: {
        ...this.state.note,
        [e.target.name]: e.target.value
      }
    });
  };
```

[You can find a working CodeSandBox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/solitary-wood-u37j3?file=/src/App.js:174-453). Note that using spread operator will not be necessary if you move out the required fields `title` and `content` out from `notes` and make them state variables directly. Check out the  `AppWithoutNote.js` file to see how it can be implemented.

Comment: Can simplify this to using same function OP used and update correct property based on `name`

Comment: You're right. Have made the changes to my answer, I just felt OP was a beginner and maybe segregation might help him understand better :)

Comment: Keeping things DRY is just as important for beginners though

Comment: Thank you dear Areeb Khan for this answer.